# How to rewrite a URL in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello I am a new with CI and i am stuck some where.

What I want is I have url like

> domain.com/article?seo=What-Software-Program&id=7

Here I am fetching the article by the id at the end
and I am using the seo for using thsse related keywords in the url for better SEO

Now what I want from that url is to look like this

> domain.com/article/What-Software-Program/id/7

I want to remove the **?seo=** from the url and replace it with /

I have sucessfully configured my routes page to route the url without the index.php and main controller

here is my route page

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(:any)'] = "main/$1";
$route['admin'] = 'admin/login';
```

and my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove /index.php/main/ from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php/main/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/main(/.*)?$ https://%1$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT**

i have the url like this domain.com/article?seo=What-Software-Program&id=7 But
this url is after i remove my default controller name and index.php the

original url is domain.com/index.php/main/article?seo=What-Software-Program&id=7 where main is the controller name article is the function name

i removed the index.php and main by route.php file and now i want to put the content of SEO in url properly.

Comment: make `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;`,  CI default follow `domain.com/article/What-Software-Program/id/7`

Comment: it does not works . i think you did not get the whole idea. i have the url like this domain.com/article?seo=What-Software-Program&id=7 But this url is after i remove my default controller name and index.php the original url is domain.com/index.php/main/article?seo=What-Software-Program&id=7 where main is the controller name article is the function name

Comment: you need url like that ? domain.com/article/What-Software-Program/id/7

Comment: yes you are right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For this type of url : domain.com/article/What-Software-Program/id/7
```

Please add below routing, in routes.php file.

```
$route['article/(:any)/id/(:num)'] = "controller_name/function_name/$1/$2";
```

Comment: i added this $route['article/(:any)/id/(:num)'] = "main/article/$1/$2";

Comment: I think there is something that goes wrong with your htaccess file.

Comment: i removed the .htaccess file to check it but still dosent works. i am sorry